# Titanium KitchenSink Example - Table Pull Refresh

Tags: titanium

May ask with below code from original 'table_view_pull_to_refresh.js' example, which part causing the header stops and scrolls up back to original position? I have been trying to dig into below code but was unable to find which line causes the header to stop once the new rows have been loaded.

Thanks

```
var win = Ti.UI.currentWindow;

function formatDate()
{
    var date = new Date();
    var datestr = date.getMonth()+'/'+date.getDate()+'/'+date.getFullYear();
    if (date.getHours()>=12)
    {
        datestr+=' '+(date.getHours()==12 ? date.getHours() : date.getHours()-12)+':'+date.getMinutes()+' PM';
    }
    else
    {
        datestr+=' '+date.getHours()+':'+date.getMinutes()+' AM';
    }
    return datestr;
}

var data = [
    {title:"Row 1"},
    {title:"Row 2"},
    {title:"Row 3"}
];

var lastRow = 4;

var tableView = Ti.UI.createTableView({
    data: data
});

win.add(tableView);

var border = Ti.UI.createView({
    backgroundColor:"#576c89",
    height:2,
    bottom:0
});

var tableHeader = Ti.UI.createView({
    backgroundColor:"#e2e7ed",
    width:320,
    height:60
});

// fake it til ya make it..  create a 2 pixel
// bottom border
tableHeader.add(border);

var arrow = Ti.UI.createView({
    backgroundImage:"../images/whiteArrow.png",
    width:23,
    height:60,
    bottom:10,
    left:20
});

var statusLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text:"Pull to reload",
    left:55,
    width:200,
    bottom:30,
    height:"auto",
    color:"#576c89",
    textAlign:"center",
    font:{fontSize:13,fontWeight:"bold"},
    shadowColor:"#999",
    shadowOffset:{x:0,y:1}
});

var lastUpdatedLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text:"Last Updated: "+formatDate(),
    left:55,
    width:200,
    bottom:15,
    height:"auto",
    color:"#576c89",
    textAlign:"center",
    font:{fontSize:12},
    shadowColor:"#999",
    shadowOffset:{x:0,y:1}
});

var actInd = Titanium.UI.createActivityIndicator({
    left:20,
    bottom:13,
    width:30,
    height:30
});

tableHeader.add(arrow);
tableHeader.add(statusLabel);
tableHeader.add(lastUpdatedLabel);
tableHeader.add(actInd);

tableView.headerPullView = tableHeader;


var pulling = false;
var reloading = false;

function beginReloading()
{
    // just mock out the reload
    setTimeout(endReloading,2000);
}

function endReloading()
{
    // simulate loading
    for (var c=lastRow;c<lastRow+10;c++)
    {
        tableView.appendRow({title:"Row "+c});
    }
    lastRow += 10;

    // when you're done, just reset
    tableView.setContentInsets({top:0},{animated:true});
    reloading = false;
    lastUpdatedLabel.text = "Last Updated: "+formatDate();
    statusLabel.text = "Pull down to refresh...";
    actInd.hide();
    arrow.show();
}

tableView.addEventListener('scroll',function(e)
{
    var offset = e.contentOffset.y;
    if (offset <= -65.0 && !pulling)
    {
        var t = Ti.UI.create2DMatrix();
        t = t.rotate(-180);
        pulling = true;
        arrow.animate({transform:t,duration:180});
        statusLabel.text = "Release to refresh...";
    }
    else if (pulling && offset > -65.0 && offset < 0)
    {
        pulling = false;
        var t = Ti.UI.create2DMatrix();
        arrow.animate({transform:t,duration:180});
        statusLabel.text = "Pull down to refresh...";
    }
});

tableView.addEventListener('scrollEnd',function(e)
{
    if (pulling && !reloading && e.contentOffset.y <= -65.0)
    {
        reloading = true;
        pulling = false;
        arrow.hide();
        actInd.show();
        statusLabel.text = "Reloading...";
        tableView.setContentInsets({top:60},{animated:true});
        arrow.transform=Ti.UI.create2DMatrix();
        beginReloading();
    }
});
```

Comment: Please note that the solution in your link does not work in recent versions of the Titanium SDK. I've posted a working solution [here](https://gist.github.com/3397853).

Answer (score 1):

This article actually details how it was built.

http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2010/05/how-to-create-a-tweetie-like-pull-to-refresh-table.html

"Also notice a fun method we’re using setContentInsets. This method will change the content position inset of the tableview. In this code, we’re simply lowering it by 60 pixels from the top. That ensures that 60 pixels of our header view remain visible while we’re reloading. In the endReloading will raise it with the following code tableView.setContentInsets({top:0},{animated:true});."

These are the related lines of code

```
tableView.addEventListener('scrollEnd',function(e)
{
    if (pulling && !reloading && e.contentOffset.y <= -65.0)
    {
        reloading = true;
        pulling = false;
        arrow.hide();
        actInd.show();
        statusLabel.text = "Reloading...";
        tableView.setContentInsets({top:60},{animated:true}); // *******THIS IS IT
        arrow.transform=Ti.UI.create2DMatrix();
        beginReloading();
    }
});
var pulling = false;
var reloading = false;

function beginReloading()
{
    // just mock out the reload
    setTimeout(endReloading,2000);
}

function endReloading()
{
    // simulate loading 
    for (var c=lastRow;c<lastRow+10;c++)
    {
        tableView.appendRow({title:"Row "+c});
    }
    lastRow += 10;

    // when you're done, just reset
    tableView.setContentInsets({top:0},{animated:true}); // *********THIS TOO
    reloading = false;
    lastUpdatedLabel.text = "Last Updated: "+formatDate();
    statusLabel.text = "Pull down to refresh...";
    actInd.hide();
    arrow.show();
}
```

Comment: This will not work in Android as tableView.setContentInsets(); not supported in Android